# Facebook ip not showing correct user agent

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-crawler, user-agent

There are IPs ex. `66.220.145.244` which are hitting us too much. I checked and it belongs to facebook, using the command `whois -h whois.radb.net -- '-i origin AS32934' | grep ^route`   as mentioned [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler).
I am able to get the IPs of facebook crawlers. Above IP is one of the facebook crawlers.

According to facebook such crawlers will show user-agent as `facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)`  or `facebookexternalhit/1.1` but i am seeing none of these. What i am seeing is `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.59 Safari/537.36`.

My setup is `cloudflare -> Load Balancer -> nginx -> app`.

I am completely confused why this is coming. It is messing up our analytics a lot. Is there any way to contact facebook and ask them to look into? I am not able to find any at my level. Any further guidance on this would be awesome.

Comment: Not sure what your site is or how much traffic you're getting, but are you sure it's not just someone that works at Facebook browsing your site?  In any case, you could probably try e-mailing domain@facebook.com or noc@fb.com, as registered with ARIN.  https://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-66-220-144-0-1/pft?s=66.220.145.244

Comment: We are getting thousands of hits from this ip which sometimes go close to million. So definitely no one at fb is browsing our site. I will try contacting facebook at given address. Thanks :)

Comment: What URL is being hit from these IPs?

Comment: We are a company which prepare fb quizzes. So question page of those quizzes are getting hit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough rep to comment so I have to respond this way. I see the same thing. It has come and gone over the last couple months. I have a couple dozen community pages my app posts to automatically, and there will be periods of time (days on end) where shortly after posting and just after the FB crawler scrapes my pages, it is hit by this other IP from Facebook.  Typically it hits a few seconds after the normal bot, but is so soon and regular that it is definitely a bot and not a person (as one of the commenters suggested).

I am getting a different user agent than you, however it is from the same IP (66.220.145.244):

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1 Safari/603.1.30"
```

It affects all my pages and posts at once for a period (days on end), then it stops for all of them (for a period of a week or more). I noted today it is "back" so I searched for the topic and found this post.

I do note that the referring URL is from l.facebook.com for these, which is FB's external link manager thingy.  If I hit that referring URL then I see a message:

> Leaving Facebook
>   We're just checking that you want to follow a link to 
>   this website: http://URL_TO_MY_PAGE

So my guess is this is a validator for the external link system, however why it is only invoked from time to time I don't understand.  I have a hunch they may spot check apps from time to time to make sure that the website is not changing content for the FB bot compared to normal browsers. Still, I don't think it's great that they pretend to be a browser they are not as it does mess up metrics.

As a solution I'm thinking about filtering from my metrics all hits on my site that occur within 5-10 seconds of when I share it on FB.

Comment: Nice observation dan. Are you somehow able to contact someone who can speak on this with some authority?